# Inserting AngularJs ng-model in MVC DropDownListFor

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dropdownlistfor

I've hardcoded the values of the drop down list as stated [here](https://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/how-to-simple-html-dropdownlistfor-mvc-net/) but I can't figure out how I could implement AngularJS's **ng-model** inside the `<select>` in this particular setup so I could insert `ng-model="categoryValue"` and get the drop down list values.

```
<div class="editor-field" ng-model="categoryValue">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ticketType, 
            new SelectList(
              new List<Object>{
                   new { value = "Hardware/Devices" , text = "Hardware/Devices" },
                   new { value = "Software/Drivers" , text = "Software/Drivers" },
                   new { value = "Access Tools" , text = "Access Tools"}
                },
              "value",
              "text",
               1))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ticketType)
        </div>
```

Code above translates into

```
<select id="ticketType" name="ticketType">
<option value="Hardware/Devices">Hardware/Devices</option>
<option value="Software/Drivers">Software/Drivers</option>
<option value="Access Tools">Access Tools</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove ng-model from div and apply on dropdownlist as below hope it'll work

```
<div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ticketType, 
            new SelectList(
              new List<Object>{
                   new { value = "Hardware/Devices" , text = "Hardware/Devices" },
                   new { value = "Software/Drivers" , text = "Software/Drivers" },
                   new { value = "Access Tools" , text = "Access Tools"}
                },
              "value",
              "text",
               1),new
                   {
                       ng_model = "categoryValue",
                   })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ticketType)
        </div>
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you :)
Encountered a couple articles that suggests the same but I didn't quite get where to put the "new" so it became a bit troublesome for me.